# Android target sdk version 17 and above

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-5.0-lollipop

In my AndroidManifest.xml I have defined the target api level to 17:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="13"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

In my java code, I want to access the [Lollipop constant](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html#LOLLIPOP) which is added in API 21.

```
//ERROR: LOLLIPOP cannot be resolved
Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP
```

But I got error LOLLIPOP cannot be resolved.

I am thinking probably I should explicitly declare in AndroidManifest.xml that the target api level is **17 and above**. So I tried :

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="13"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17+" />
```

But the LOLLIPOP constant still cannot be resolved in java code. How can I use the LOLLIPOP constant then? I mean, of course set target level to 21 works but my main question is can I make my project be aware of that I want to target **not only api level 17 but also above**?

Answer (score 2):

> How can I use the LOLLIPOP constant then?

Set your build target to be 21 or higher. In Eclipse, that is in Project > Properties > Android. In Android Studio, that is the `compileSdkVersion` in your `build.gradle` file.

Comment: I know this solution, this is not the answer for my question. My question is can I target to **17 and above**. Do you mean the answer is NO? Only way to get it work is to target the highest api level which support the code ?

Comment: @user842225: "this is not the answer for my question" -- yes, it is, for the question that I quoted in my answer. "My question is can I target to 17 and above" -- `targetSdkVersion` has nothing to do with the availability of the `LOLLIPOP` constant. That is controlled by the `compileSdkVersion` (a.k.a., build target in Eclipse). If you want that constant, you need to be compiling against Android 5.0 or higher. "My question is can I target to 17 and above" -- I have no idea what you think that question means and what that has to do with the `LOLLIPOP` constant.